# Nodejs assigning values to global constant variable

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a function in nodejs where I am fetching customers from SQL Database and I need to assign it to variable to use it for further processing.

Below is my code:

```
function getCustomers() {

    var i;
    var conn = new sql.Connection(dbConfig);
    var _customerName;
    conn.connect().then(function () {
        var req = new sql.Request(conn);
        req.query("SELECT CustomerName FROM CUSTOMERS").then(function (recordset) {
            //console.log(recordset);
            for (i = 0; i <= recordset.length; i++) {
                _customerName =  String(recordset[i].NAMECUST);
            }
            return _customerName;
            // conn.close();
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
            //conn.close();
        });
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
    finalize(obj, function () {
        return _customerName;
    });


}
//console.log();

const categories = {
  "headquarters": {
    "category": "headquarters",
    "suggestion": "Headquarters",
    "facts": [
      "Customer 1",
      "Customer 2",
      "Customer 3"
    ],
    "factPrefix": "Okay, here's a Customer fact."
  }


};
```

I am not able retrieve the value from a function and assign it to categories variable.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking... when do you execute the `getCustomers()` function? How are you using `categories`? This obviously isn't all of the code, so I'm not sure what you're asking exactly.

Comment: actually i have a function where i am retrieving customers with the name of GetCustomers.

and then i want to assign all the fetched customers to the global variable called categories. I want to know how to assign it after executing the function.

Comment: Still not following... are you just asking how to assign a value to a variable in JS? Like `categories.headquarters.facts.push(_customerName)` ??

Comment: Yes i want exactly this.

Comment: But the problem is if I assign value categories.headquarters.facts.push(_customerName) within a function, it gets reset outside the function.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a variable at top 
var categories = {};

and assign value inside the method GetCustomers().

But this is not the correct way to do this, you have to use callback method and return data in callback method.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to push assignment code line into callback function.
Your code may look like this:

```
const categories = {
  "headquarters": {
    "category": "headquarters",
    "suggestion": "Headquarters",
    "facts": [],
    "factPrefix": "Okay, here's a Customer fact."
  }
function getCustomers() {

    var i;
    var conn = new sql.Connection(dbConfig);
    var _customerName;
    conn.connect().then(function () {
        var req = new sql.Request(conn);
        req.query("SELECT CustomerName FROM CUSTOMERS").then(function (recordset) {
            //console.log(recordset);
            for (i = 0; i <= recordset.length; i++) {
               categories.headequaters.facts.push(recordset[i].NAMECUST)
            }
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
            //conn.close();
        });
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
    finalize(obj, function () {
        return _customerName;
    });
}
};
```

Comment: Oh sorry, actually, you do not have to return anything, after the loop completes, the categories is filled with customer data. I edited the answer